# Simple Camel test fails with no messages recieved

Tags: apache-camel

Am using Spring Boot and I have just added camel to it.

I have a simple camel route setup :

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file://in").to("file://out");  
  }
}
```

When I try to create simple test for this route with :

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class MyRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {

  @Autowired
  private CamelContext camelContext;

  @Produce(uri = "file://in")
  private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:file://out")
  private MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;

  @Test
  public void routeTest() throws Exception {
    mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
    producerTemplate.sendBody("Test");
    mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
  }
}
```

It fails with

```
mock://file://out Received message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>
```

Not sure what could be a problem here. I have producer template that has uri as my route from point and am mocking to endpoint with EndpointInject and the the mock uri?

Comment: Configure [AdviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) 
Detailed example: http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2014/04/24/correctly-using-camels-advicewith-in-unit-tests/

Comment: Tried, same error , strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
   @Override
  public String isMockEndpoints() {
    return "*";
  }
```

This should mock all the enpoints and then you can use mock:file:out for example

Comment: thx  , that worked!
Still not sure why didnt it work with @SpringBootTest annotation

Answer (score 1):

Fixed but not 100%

If I change route from real one

```
from("file://in").to("file://out");
```

to

```
from("file://in").to("mock:out");
```

And in my test override

```
@Override
  protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new MyRoute();
  }
```

to create specific route

and strangest of all ! Had to remove :

```
@SpringBootTest
```

and after that

```
private CamelContext camelContext;
```

And then it started working !

But unfortunately not what I need, still there are things that need to be fixed, I would like to use my real prod route !

```
from("file://in").to("file://out");
```

And if possible not use advise on route , but just mock it , tried with 
mock:file://out in test, but it didnt work :(
and also , it does not work with @SpringBootTest ??? very strange ?!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not misstaken you are mocking your output endpoint yet your endpoint endpoint is a file endpoint. When you send a message you need to drop a message to whereever the file endpoint is polling. Otherwise you need to mock that as well.

Comment: sry but am confused and not so sure what is your idea . I think this producerTemplate.sendBody("Test"); would put a message in the route ?

Comment: Yes, but your route is listening on a file endpoint and not a direct endpoint. Your error is saying that is expecting one message but didn't receive any. Add a mock endpoint to your file:in and send a message to the endpoint mock:file:in instead. Alternatively use replaceFromWith(). See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032612/camel-mock-test-using-file-as-input